# How to check for null fields in excel import

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Am import from Excel into an application and then save in the database using asp.net mvc and wcf.
It generates error because of the null fields. I check my database and my code, I saw that I allow null in those fields

See my Controller below.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ImportCacExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    var bodsList = new List<CAC>();
    if (FileUpload != null)
    {

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
        if (true)//FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        {
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
            {
                var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                // if(currentSheet.Count)
                var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                {
                    var bod = new CAC();

                    bod.RC_NUMBER = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();//.ToString().Trim();
                    bod.COMPANY_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();//.ToString().Trim();
                    bod.OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();//.ToString().Trim();    
                    bod.ADDRESS_STREET = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
                    bod.ADDRESS_CITY = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();
                    bod.ADDRESS_STATE = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();
                    bod.ADDRESS_PMB = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value.ToString();
                    bod.ADDRESS_POBOX = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 8].Value.ToString();
                    bod.ADDRESS_LGA = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 9].Value.ToString();

                    try
                    {
                        bod.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/" + workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value);//.ToString().Trim();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        data.Add("Bad Date format for item at row " + rowIterator);
                    }

                    bod.ACTION_STATUS = 1;
                    bod.CREATED_DATE = DateTime.Now;
                    bodsList.Add(bod);
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in bodsList)
            {
                _cacService.AddCac(item);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        { 
            data.Add("<ul>");
            data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        data.Add("<ul>");
        if (FileUpload == null) data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");
        data.Add("</ul>");
        data.ToArray();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Please how do I alter my code in the controller to ckeck if the fields like

1. RC_NUMBER
2. COMPANY_NAME
3. OWNERSHIP_STRUCTURE

are null or empty, It should indicate to the user.
But if the fields like

1. ADDRESS_STREET
2. ADDRESS_CITY
3. ADDRESS_STATE
4. ADDRESS_PMB
5. ADDRESS_POBOX
6. ADDRESS_LGA

are null or empty, It should add null to the excel, and save null to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply user input validation, so null values are not allowed to pass. Client side validation, for e.g. using javascript would be best. This prevents the form from being posted. This also must include  server side validation in the controller, to protect against the client side validation failing and so to prevent program errors.

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString())
{
    // Do something to prevent form submission.
}
else
{

    bod.RC_NUMBER = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
}
```

For all the values that are allowed to be null. It may be simpler to initialise them to null. Then check is the values are indeed null and if they're not, assign that value to the `CAC` attribute.

```
bod.ADDRESS_STREET = null;
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString())
{
    bod.ADDRESS_STREET = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: **Thanks a lot, it works.**  Please I have a question in order to prevent future occurrence. I used  wcf with the asp.net mvc. In the wcf I used data annotation. But while consuming the the service, it is not implementing the data annotation. Thats why I have the error you helped me to solve. How do I make it to implement the data annotation